# Using jstl in sightly

Tags: html, jstl, aem, sightly

I have a jstl which is used for cleaning the html fragment between the tag from a jsp file. But in current scenario, all my components are in sightly. I want to achieve the same. Is it possible to somehow use that tag in sightly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use JSP tag libraries in Sightly but there's a way you can work around this limitation.

You can include other scripts in your Sightly script using the [`data-sly-include`](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#228-include) attribute.

Here's what it does according to [the documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/block-statements.html#include):

> Replaces the content of the host element with the markup generated by the indicated HTML template file (Sightly, JSP, ESP etc.) when it is processed by its corresponding template engine. The rendering context of the included file will not include the current Sightly context (that of the including file); Consequently, for inclusion of Sightly files, the current `data-sly-use` would have to be repeated in the included file

and more on [Sightly/JSP interoperability](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly.html#Moving%20from%20JSP%20to%20Sightly)

> moving to Sightly is not necessarily an all-or-nothing choice, because components written in Sightly are compatible with components written in JSP or ESP. Meaning that existing projects can without a problem use Sightly for new components, while keeping JSP for existing components.
>
> Even within the same component, Sightly files can be used alongside JSPs and ESPs. For example, a JSP can include a Sightly file like this,
>
> `<cq:include script="footer.html"/>`
>
> and a Sightly file can include a JSP like this,
>
> `<div data-sly-include="footer.jsp"></div>`

If you make sure that the taglib is visible to the JSP (proper includes in your JSP or the `global.jsp` it's referring to), you should be able to use the taglib in a JSP and then refer to the JSP in your Sightly files.

As an alternative, you could write a Use class or a Sling Model in Java implementing functionality similar to that the custom tag provides.

There might be a different, more elegant way to achieve the desired result but it's hard to say without knowing what exactly the tag in question is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @HariomTomar that sounds like something you might want to keep out of AEM. Have you considered setting up `mod_pagespeed` on Apache? If you want to stick with the Sightly solution, calling a JSP, in which you use the tag should do the trick.

Comment: The tag takes the html in between the tag and minifies it. For ex:- 
'<cleaningTag>
  <a href="something"></a>
</cleaningTag>'

Comment: That way i will have to include one jsp file on top of the html code and one below.. opening the tag in one and closing in the other, which obviously will cause jsp parsing exception.

Comment: You're right, you'd have to move all of the enclosed HTML to the JSP then. I think you should look into pagespeed. You can deploy it in front of AEM and have it minify all pages requested by the users, saving bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use any jsp tags in sightly (it's an html not a jsp at the end). The current implementation also do not allow to define any custom tags.